# Show connecting mode on VOIPPhoneCall status bar

Tags: uwp, statusbar, windows-10-mobile, windows-phone-voip

I am implementing VoIP application on windows phone 10, I am using VoipPhoneCall.

When a user makes a call and bring an app to background, VoipPhoneCall is showed, and I want connecting mode in that status bar is showed correctly, when connecting mode is dialing it should be "Dialing", and when connecting mode is connected, it should be duration time. This is VoipPhoneCall status bar of Viber, and I want to do same.

[image: Voip Phone Call status bar of Viber]

Please help me, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want connecting mode in that status bar is showed correctly, when connecting mode is dialing it should be "Dialing", and when connecting mode is connected, it should be duration time

The key point is, we don't need to call the [`VoipPhoneCall.NotifyCallActive` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.phone.networking.voip.voipphonecall.notifycallactive.aspx) after using [`VoipCallCoordinator.RequestNewOutgoingCall` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj662966.aspx).

I used the official VoIP sample to explain.

See the [VccCallHelper.cs](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/VoIP/cs/VoipTasks/Helpers/VccCallHelper.cs) file in the **VoipTasks** project.

Please notice the `NewOutgoingCall` method([LINK](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/VoIP/cs/VoipTasks/Helpers/VccCallHelper.cs#L92)):

```
VoipPhoneCall call = vCC.RequestNewOutgoingCall( context, contactName, serviceName, VoipPhoneCallMedia.Audio);
if (call != null)
{
                call.EndRequested += Call_EndRequested;
                call.HoldRequested += Call_HoldRequested;
                call.RejectRequested += Call_RejectRequested;
                call.ResumeRequested += Call_ResumeRequested;

                call.NotifyCallActive();//Here!!

                Current.VoipCall = call;

                Current.StartAudio();

                status = true;
}
```

If we call the `VoipPhoneCall.NotifyCallActive` method, the status bar will show the active timer. So just comment this line, the notification will be sent in the `AnswerRequested` method, see `NewIncomingCall` method->[`Call_AnswerRequested`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/VoIP/cs/VoipTasks/Helpers/VccCallHelper.cs#L184)